# Hey guys, I wonder, is there another way how to write this:

Tags: if-statement

I wrote this condition. I am using C.

```
 if ((ch < 'A') || (ch > 'Z'));
```

But I was wondering, is there another way how to write this condition?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Oh, I am using C.